# Service redeliver intent strange behavior?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm using a Service with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` and with that Service I want to upload to a server a video and some metadata that comes along with the video.

As far as I can tell I need to use `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` and not `START_STICKY` since the first will try and get the data from the intent again and I need those data.

What I have noticed to happen is that it uploads the video with its metadata to my server correctly but it will reupload it again randomly the next 1-2 days.

I have not tested this behavior a lot but it has already happened 4-5 times. Am i doing something wrong ? Should I have added something to my `Service` it to mark it as correct when it successfully uploads my data so it won't redeliver ?

My code :

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    MyApplication.get(this).applicationComponent().inject(this);

    getIntentValues(intent);

    buildNotification();

    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

private void getIntentValues(Intent intent) {
// Here I get some strings from the intent ... 
}

private void buildNotification() {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    builder.setContentTitle("Upload");
    builder.setContentText("Thank you for uploading!");
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    // Start the Service in the Foreground
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    Thread taskThread = new Thread(new UploadVideoTask());
    taskThread.start();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the service with `stopSelf(startId)` after your video was uploaded successfully.

Otherwise the service will be relaunched after being stopped by the system, receive initial intent and upload a video again.

Read description to the [START_REDEVLIVER_INTENT](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) carefully:

> if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then it will be scheduled for a
>   restart and the last delivered Intent **re-delivered** to it again via
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int). This Intent will remain scheduled
>   for redelivery until the service calls **stopSelf(int)** with the start ID
>   provided to onStartCommand(Intent, int, int). The service will not
>   receive a onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) call with a null Intent
>   because it will will only be re-started if it is not finished
>   processing all Intents sent to it (and any such pending events will be
>   delivered at the point of restart).

Comment: hey i have same issue - i am using  START_REDEVLIVER_INTENT for generating bulk notifications and dismiss each manually. now if i am using stopself(int) it only dismiss first one if try to dismiss another app creased.. can you pls tell how to get each start id so i can dismiss each one..Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know the solution. You have to ask this as a separate question and attach some code, so guys will understand what's going on.